# Comparing textbox.Text with a variable

Tags: c#

I'm comparing textBox2.text to a variable called 'word', word contains a random word coming from a txt file. The user needs to guess the word by placing the word in the textBox2 and if the user is correct a messageBox comes up to show he won.

the code I wrote doesn't show any errors and seems good to me, maybe theirs some other way to do this application.

```
string word; // variable for random word generated 
word = RandomWord(); // Calling random word generator method

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox2.Text == word)
        {
            label4.Text = "You Won";
            MessageBox.Show("You Guessed The Word = " + (word), "You won");
        }
        else
        {
            DoesNotMatch();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the code written does not work

Comment: Explain "does not work".  What happens?  Also, please edit your question with details like that, don't post in comments.

Comment: ensure case sensitivety

Comment: Additionally, please take the time to format the code in your post - imagine you were trying to answer the question... how would you want the question to look?

Comment: What happens in the DoesNotMatch() method? Where is the issue, you're expecting a MessageBox yet nothing happens?

Comment: case is important. `word` is not equal to ¨Word` or `WORD`. Try something like `textBox2.Text.Trim().ToLower() == word.Trim().ToLower()`

Comment: or `textBox2.Text.Equals(word, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` (off the top of my head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix your formatting like I did in this answer.  Then, there are some things to remember about strings:

1. They are a `nullable` type.
2. Even one character being of a different case breaks equality.
3. Any whitespace, including trailing spaces/padding, can break equality.

   ```
   string word; // variable for random word generated word = RandomWord(); 
   // Calling random word generator method  
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {    
        if(textBox2.Text != null && textBox2.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
           {
             if (textBox2.Text.Trim().ToLower() == word.Trim().ToLower())
             {
                 label4.Text = "You Won";
                 MessageBox.Show("You Guessed The Word = " + (word), "You won");
             }
             else
             {
                 DoesNotMatch();    
             }
           } else { throw new ApplicationException("Invalid entry, please try again.");}
       }
   ```

With those concerns in mind, I applied `string.Trim()` and `.Lower()` to ensure any whitespace is cleaned up and case is ignored. Before I even get that far, I confirm that text is actually present in the `.Text` property of the `control`. If it isn't, we `throw` an `exception` (although you may just want to pop a `MessageBox`).  There are cleaner ways to do this and account for various cultural differences, but this is the quick, dirty way you'd normally see in an office environment.